# Entire sub-directory redirect via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I need to temporarily shut down a web sub-directory and all of its sub-directories without physically removing the files off the server. I want to redirect anyone and everyone to a specific webpage if they try to hit any page inside the sub-directory or its sub-directories. And I want the redirect to go to a page stored in the sub-directory because that's where its css and all its images are located.

I am trying these directives but I am not having success:

```
Options -ExecCGI -Indexes
DirectoryIndex /sub-dir/interim.php
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !interim.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sub-dir/interim.php [L,NC,QSA]
```

Has anyone ever done something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sound like it might make some kind of never ending loop.  Can you redirect to a different domain that points to the same directory?  Or add a new subdomain like offline.example.com that points to your site.   You can use RedirectMatch to match any request and specify a temp http status so the client knows the redirect is temporary.

```
RedirectMatch temp (.*) http://offline.example.com/interim.php
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I am just going to remove the directories from the server temporarily. It's taking too long to be "clever" about it.